# Typed Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, class, object

I want to create a typed array in Javascript.

For example when I create a class like this:

```
export default class AnalyticData {
    constructor(collection = []) {
        return collection.map((item) => new AnalyticDatum(item))
    }
}
```

and after I make `myData = new AnalyticData()` the type of myData is Array and not `AnalyticData`

Does anyone know how to make sure that I have a `AnalyticData` type and not an Array?

I ask this because in my vue component I have this:

```
    props: {
        analyticData: {
            type: AnalyticData,
            required: true,
        },
    },
```

And so this warning :

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "analyticData". Expected AnalyticData, got Array
```

Does anybody know how to create a `typed Array` in `JS` ?

Comment: There are such things as typed arrays, but they are for a completely  different and specialized purpose. General arrays in JavaScript are not typed; any element of an array can contain a value of any type.

Comment: ok, but do You think that is possible to have an `AnalyticData` type for `analyticData` prop ?

Comment: If you're programming in JavaScript, no. That's why people invented things like TypeScript. JavaScript variables and properties are not typed. *Values* have types, but not variables/properties.

Comment: but it's working with an object

Comment: @Ady642 You shouldn't `return` anything from your constructor. That is causing `myData` being an array instead of a `AnalyticData` instance. I don't have a clue what you actually want to do with the result of that `.map()` though. Possibly you want to assign it to a property instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `AnalyticDatum` is a typo, but you can have custom types using `extends`.

```
export default class AnalyticData extends Array {
  constructor(collection = []) {
    super().push(...collection);
  }
};
```

If `AnalyticDatum` is instead another class to define `AnalyticData` items, you can still use the `map(...)` procedure:

```
export default class AnalyticData extends Array {
  constructor(collection = []) {
    super().push(...collection.map(item => new AnalyticDatum(item)));
  }
};
```

In both cases, the `new AnalyticData` will be an instance of `AnalyticData`, so whatever type checker you have in there, shouldn't have issues.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i still have the warning about the array type...

Comment: then you should likely file an issue in vue, as `new AnalyticData` is an `Array` but it's exactly an instance of `AnalyticData` first, so the type checker is doing something wrong.

Comment: oh yes sorry you're right: https://jsfiddle.net/sx85e27g/3/. It's something else so

Comment: the problem is that in my Vue app I have an Observable(from the Vue reactivy I think) so It's considered as an Array by the prop validation

Answer (score 0):

You can create number arrays easily in javascript, [as explained in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays). For an object array is not that easy, and if you put in them dynamic data (like strings) you have to reserve space for that data. That is somehow low level, I would not recommend it for a javascript project.

I suggest to use typescript (if it makes sense in your project). Typed programming in typescript is easy:

```
interface AnalyticDatum {
  date: Date;
  info: string;
}

const data: AnalyticDatum[] = [{
    date: new Date("2019-07-27"),
    info: 'Some text',
},{
    date: new Date("2019-09-24"),
    info: 'Some other text',
}];

data.push({
    date: new Date("2019-12-27"),
    info: 'New entry',
});

console.log(data);
```

[Run this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIjgGwJ5mAgETjAFcBbZAbwChlkATYiALmSMgG5blQYB7VgGcwUUAHMuAX2rUEfEMIbE4rdFlz525ANoBdZAF5k2mnTqNIrEBADubJgAoARACYADAEYAnAFo3Adh8XfycASgAabjpeAWQAcgBlPjIUSAAPMDjIyXDTMwsWZGs7dghnd28-XxcAFjDIsx4QflZE5JQ+MAALaGR0zOzdLmoLOAA6AAcSQS6HPPMmK1t7SHLPXw8XIJCIqKaW+IA5ZYhwKGws6klQ4bkFPkwIMcw+MQdRm+4gA)